# How use apply() with a function with multiple parameters ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I have this function to extend dates, and I would like to use the parameters OpenHour and CloseHour:

```
def extends_dates(x,OpenHour,CloseHour):
    if len(x.groupby(x.Timestamp.dt.date)) == 1:
        return x.Timestamp
    else:
        # Create daterange
        d_range = pd.date_range(start=x.Timestamp.dt.date.min(), end=x.Timestamp.dt.date.max()) \
            .repeat(2) \
            .to_series() \
            .iloc[1:-1] \
            .reset_index(drop=True) \
            .apply(pd.Timestamp)
        # Set hours of all date
        news = [d.replace(hour=CloseHour) if i % 2 == 0 else d.replace(hour=OpenHour)
                for i, d in enumerate(d_range)]
        # Add min (from dataframe)
        news.insert(0, min(x.Timestamp))
        # Add max date (from dataframe)
        news.append(max(x.Timestamp))
        return pd.Series(news, name="Timestamp")
```

But when I used it with 5h and 20h, it doesn't work:

```
 out = df.groupby(df.index // 2).apply(extends_dates, args=(5,20)).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()

TypeError: extends_dates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Before, I use it like this without OpenHour and CloseHour in parameters:

```
 out = df.groupby(df.index // 2).apply(extends_dates).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
```

Comment: Does this work `...apply(extends_data, OpenHours=5, CloseHour=20)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang it's works just one time, when I execute it several times and I change the parameter OpenHour and CloseHour there is no changements...  And I need to apply it several times...

Comment: @QuangHoang can you answer the question please ? not with a comment.
Because it's ok for me ;) ! thanks a lot